# Import leaflet plugin into Angular project

Tags: angular, plugins, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm looking to import the plugin https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet.imageTransform into an Angular project. I've add the script into the src folder. it's imported in angular.json file in the scripts sections.

In my map component I created a variable declare const ImageTransform: any; When I call it it's returning

> "core.js:6014 ERROR ReferenceError: ImageTransform is not defined"

So maybe I'm doing this completely wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I need to cast to make it works : `(L as any).imageTransform(url, anchors, options);`